# How to access a specific $scope variable when loading a different .html file?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope, html-table

First of all, sorry about the title, I just wan't sure how to word this question.

So I'm making a task manager using AngularJS. I have a form for the user to fill with the details when he's creating a new task. I use `ng-model` to save these values to my `$scope`. Here's how I save them:

```
$scope.add = function(tasks)
{
    {
        $scope.tasks.push({
            'id': tasks.id,
            'title': tasks.title,
            'start_day': tasks.start_day,
            'start_time':tasks.start_time,
            'start_date':tasks.start_day + " " + tasks.start_time,
            'end_day': tasks.end_day,
            'end_time': tasks.end_time,
            'end_date':tasks.end_day + " " + tasks.end_time,
            'type': tasks.type,
            'description': tasks.description
        });
        localStorage.setItem('tasks',JSON.stringify($scope.tasks));
    }
};
```

Then, as you can see, I save these values to the local storage. I have an array called `tasks` with all the tasks the user created. I then display these tasks in a table with this:

```
<table id="datatable" class="display" ng-cloak>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><b>ID</b></th>
        <th><b>Title</b></th>
        <th><b>Start Date</b></th>
        <th><b>End Date</b></th>
        <th><b>Type</b></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks track by $index">
        <td ng-click="details(task)">{{task.id}}</td>
        <td ng-click="details(task)">{{task.title}}</td>
        <td ng-click="details(task)">{{task.start_date}}</td>
        <td ng-click="details(task)">{{task.end_date}}</td>
        <td ng-click="details(task)">{{task.type}}</td>
        <td><a ng-click="remove(task)" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light red<i class="material-icons">clear</i></a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then, the objective is that you can click any row and load a new page with all the task details. I do this with the function `details()`, which has the following code:

```
$scope.details = function (task)
{
    $window.location.href = 'table.html';
}
```

This loads the file `table.html` and what I want **is to display in this page all the task details**, i.e., the ID, the title, the description, etc.

What I don't know is **how to only display the specific task that you click on**. For example, if I click on the row with the task "Todo #1", I only want to see the details for the task "Todo #1".

Comment: Use ng-route or ui-router to set the route in such a way that the page doesn't reload. Then you don't have to go to localStorage, and you can use the route definition to define which one you want. Please [review the tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I've been trying all day but I can't seem to make this work with ng-route. I'm using Datatables and when I change the view without reloading (by clicking on a task to see the details) and then come back to the task list, that messes up my table and the buttons stop working. I don't know why that happens.

Comment: Use the debugger tools in your browser to poke around and see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

to access this variable in other html you can use factory or service like this

```
(function() {
"use strict";
angular.module('dataModule',[])
.factory('datafactory',function(){
return {

};
});
})();
```

Now datafactory is factory we need to inject this module(dataModule) in your module and factory(datafactory) in controller

Now how to use this factory
in your function

```
$scope.details = function (task)
{
datafactory.currentTask =task
$window.location.href = 'table.html';
}
```

Now this datafactory stores your variable that can we used in any controller and later on also you can use this factory to store any such variable for global use
like this datafactory.Myvariable ="hasd"//assign here

Now to use this variable
Suppose you want to use this variable in another page table.html there on

```
// in html ng-init ="$scopeInit()"

in controller
$scopeInit =function(){
$scope.localTask =datafactory.currentTask
}
and use $scope.localTask
```

suppose html looks something like this

```
<div ng-controller ="my-controller" ng-init ="$scopeInit()">
<table id="datatable" class="display" ng-cloak>
<thead>
<tr>
<th><b>ID</b></th>
<th><b>Title</b></th>
<th><b>Start Date</b></th>
<th><b>End Date</b></th>
<th><b>Type</b></th>
<th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="task in tasks track by $index">
<td ng-click="details(task)">{{task.id}}</td>
<td ng-click="details(task)">{{task.title}}</td>
<td ng-click="details(task)">{{task.start_date}}</td>
<td ng-click="details(task)">{{task.end_date}}</td>
<td ng-click="details(task)">{{task.type}}</td>
<td><a ng-click="remove(task)" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light red<i class="material-icons">clear</i></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div>

//in controller

$scopeInit =function(){
$scope.task =datafactory.currentTask
}

//$scope.task contains required array and hence table can be created
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! Do you mind explaining that last bit of code a little bit better? I couldn't quite understand where I'm supposed to write that.