# How to change stored value in Value recipe of angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

From the angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers), I can see that a value recipe can be used to store some information that can be injected in different modules. So I wanted to use this for storing some user related configurations in my angular app.

What I am doing right now:

Set a value by default-

```
app.value('display', {
        header: true,
        switcher: true
    })
```

I have a header and switcher in my views that I want to show or hide based on the value of header and switcher coming from above assignment.

This part of display and hiding works fine. What I want is that if some controller changes the value of header to false, header should then be hidden for that particular user. So from within my controller I just set the values to false. But on page refresh, these values are gone.

I am not sure what is going wrong here. Are we not supposed to change the value? If not, isn't that just a constant. In case we are not supposed to update values, what would be a better way to store some user related variables that will be available to entire app.

Comment: use factory or services to have a variable available through out you app

Comment: here is similar question may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840612/how-to-access-a-specific-scope-variable-when-loading-a-different-html-file/37840830#37840830

Comment: use local storage or session storage only if you wish to retain data even after refresh like user name such data can be stored in session or local storage other wise use factory or services to get data thoroughout  app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a factory like

```
(function() {
"use strict";
angular.module('dataModule',[])
.factory('datafactory',function(){
return {

};
});
})();
```

Now datafactory can be accessed any where in application just you need to inject this module in required module and factory in required controller

use like this

```
datafactory.myReusableVar  ="something"
```

later on in someother controller

```
$scope.myLocalVar =datafactory.myReusableVar

//using session storage
var x ="value"// x can be any data type string,array, or object
sessionStorage.setItem("mySessionItem",x)
$scope.mysessionValue =sessionStorage.getItem("mySessionItem")
```

Comment: This is giving the same issue. Reload the page and its gone. I will update the question with what I tried.

Comment: hi vivek,
if you want to retain value even after refresh then you need to use session   storage or local storage this is how you can use

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on page refresh the current context is lost (including all the variables), you should resolve your issue by storing the data inside your browser's localStorge.
check this module
https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage